# How to send push notifications only to users having app version > 4.1.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an app released recently with new pages and I want to send push notifications (which points to those new pages) to only those users having the latest app version(4.1.1).

I am using AWS-SNS to push notifications from backend code(ruby on rails)

Can anyone please tell me how we could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SNS service doesn't have capability to detect endpoints (i.e users using a particular app version). Therefore, I would like to refer you to another AWS service called Amazon Pinpoint which from my research supports this use-case.

In summary, when using Amazon Pinpoint service with your app and users install the app Amazon Pinpoint creates endpoints (i.e ***a repository of audience data***). This data consists of:

- Any custom attributes or metrics that you record.
- [Demographics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/analytics-demographics.html#analytics-demographics-description). See sample illustration below:

[image: Amazon_Pinpoint-demographic.png]

Using the sample demographics data as shown above you can do the following :

1. Create [Segment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/segments.html) that include users using app version(x.x.x). See sample illustration below:

[image: Amazon_Pinpoint-Segments.png]

2. Create a push notification [Campaign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/campaigns.html) that a targets the Segment created above.